# Trying to make countdown timer but getting undefined when passing data from componentdidmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

Here is line of my code. I can't access the data from `const { quests } = this.props;` which I'm pulling from redux state and I am getting undefined. I tried to put my code on componentDidUpdate my issue resolved from getting **undefined**. However, I can't make the time tick and my page not re-rendering.

```
 componentDidUpdate() {
        const { quests } = this.props || {}
        let getTime;
        
        getTime = quests.items?.items?.map(quests => {
            let startTime = Date.parse(quests.createdAt)
            let endTime = Date.parse(quests.expiresAt)
            let timeLimit = endTime - startTime;
            let timeDuration = moment.duration(timeLimit*1000, 'milliseconds');
            let interval = 1000;
            let today = moment().utc();
            
            quests.timeDuration = timeDuration

            setInterval(() => {
                timeDuration = moment.duration(timeDuration - interval, 'milliseconds')    
                quests.timeDuration = timeDuration
                
            }, interval)
        })
        return getTime;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe your `mapStateToProps` function isn't wired up correctly to `connect`. Please can you post the whole component with Redux bindings.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean I already get the data when calling it on render but when I put it inside the componentdidmount I'm getting undefined. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Your timer function is mutating props (which is bad) because it is directly changing quests, but it is not causing a recognizable update in state or props, so it is not rerendering. Something like this might work, without more code to go off of from your project it's hard to provide an example that's much use, but maybe this will give you an idea.

```
state = {
  quests: [],
  elapsedSeconds: 0,
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (!prevProps.quests && this.props.quests) {
    const { quests } = this.props;
    let getTime = [];
    quests.items?.items?.forEach((quest, index) => {
      let startTime = Date.parse(quest.createdAt)
      let endTime = Date.parse(quest.expiresAt)
      let timeLimit = endTime - startTime;
      let timeDuration = moment.duration(timeLimit*1000, 'milliseconds');
      let today = moment().utc();
      getTime.push(timeDuration);
    })
    this.setState({quests: getTime});

    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(({elapsedSeconds, quests}) => {
        quests = quests.map(time => time - 1000)
        return {elapsedSeconds: elapsedSeconds++, quests};
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```